# Java scanner separating data from an input file

Tags: java

I'm kinda new to java and I'm a little confused at the moment. Im trying to get some input data from a file and the like parse it/ and give it the correct fields for what its equal to. For example,my "in.txt"

```
Number: 2 Gender: 1 City: 4 Car: 7       
Gender: 1 City: 4 Number: 1                                                                                 
City: 2 Car: 1 Number: 3
```

I'm trying to get to where Number equals 2 and Gender equals 1, and City equals 4, etc.. So far I'm able to use java's Scanner to read the file so I know that its reading it right. So how would I be able to correspond the names to the numbers like (Number: 2). Should I split the line whenever it sees an ":"? Like give it a left and a right side, or would that mess up the rest of the line with "Gender: 1 City: 4 ..."? I'm trying different things as I'm typing this and I'm just becoming stuck in how I would separate the data from the file. I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you. This is my scanner file I'm using to get the file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class example{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inFile = new File("in.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: So you have different fields in each line? What are you using them for? Is it like Number: 1 comes with Gender & City, Number: 2 comes with Gender, City & Car, Number: 3 comes with City & Car?

Comment: Like you said you can use split ":".

Comment: @Gosu its kinda like a database. Like if I were to say "db.collection.find({City=4},{Number})"
I would get as an output
Number: 2
Number: 1

Comment: @Jure Splitting on ":" doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file or the lines are always build like you described it, you can split for spaces and search in the array for your needed value e.g. `"Number:"` (if necessary you can remove the ":") and then watch in the array at this `position + 1` and there is the value.

Splitting for ":" will end up in such an array:

```
{[Number],[ 2 Gender],[ 1 City],[ 4 Car],[ 7]}
```

so I think this is not the best solution.

Comment: Yes, the lines are always built like that. But wouldn't splitting on the spaces be a problem at the end of the line?

Comment: @King11 Why do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: Well I was thinking like for example:----  int split_index = line.lastIndexOf(":"); left = line.substring(0,split_index); right = line.subString(split_index,line.length());---- This won't work the way that I'm thinking of. Like I want Number, Gender, City, and Car to all be the left and 2, 1, 4, 7 to all the the right. If I split on a space, then only Number will be left and the rest of the line would be the right

Answer (score 0):

One way to tackle the problem of identifying each key/value pair in each line would be to use regular expressions to find each pair in a line. The [Java Tutorials on Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) provide a good, and fairly comprehensive, starting point on the topic.

To get you started on this, the regular expression `[A-Za-z]+: [0-9]+` will isolate each key-value pair for you, and a regular expression helper such as [this web page at regexplanet.com](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) will help greatly with testing and to start to identify the code you would need.

Comment: They are not arrays, they are just text/words in a text file

Comment: Yep - and regular expressions are perfect for parsing raw text to identify values within it. Regular expressions are designed to work on raw strings, not arrays.

Comment: BTW this answer is deliberately vague in terms of not providing the exact code, as regular expressions is one of those topics I believe we should all get to grips with and master, it is one of the most valuable time investments we can make when learning to write code :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get these numbers?
1:
If i understand correctly,you could do this.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Number {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\d+";
        String candidate = "Number: 2 Gender: 1 City: 4 Car: 7  ";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(candidate);
        while(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

2:if you can format your data,you can format to JSON ,and use json-lib.jar